# All of my content nodes are showing up as public /content dump pages?

Tags: nodes

I'm not sure if I can explain this correctly, I just started working in Drupal 7 last week, and I'm working with an established site.

We sell products. Each individual model is classified as a content type, but does not have its own URL. Somehow we have /content pages (like ourwebsite.com/content/model#) visible to the public that contain all of the information on each model, just dumped into an ugly list. These pages are ranking in Google and getting traffic. I don't know why they are visible, I've tried turning off URL alias and it doesn't work. I know I can do redirects, but we have over 1500 models and that would take a very long time. I'm wondering if there's a node or view setting somewhere that I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: You need the Rabbit Hole module to restrict access to single node pages. So they'll only be visible in Views, Blocks or wherever you reference them.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153911/rabbit-hole-whats-the-recommended-setting-for-content-that-should-not-be-direc